# create stripe invoice with specific invoice items, excluding pending invoice items

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create manual stripe invoices but don't want it to create the invoice from pending invoice items. For example, I have 3 pending invoice items that I **do not** want include on this manual invoice.

`Pending Line Items:
Item 1
Item 2`

`New Invoice:
Item 3`

**How do I create a blank invoice, then manually assign Item 3 to it, with out adding 1 and 2?**

Comment: You can't at this point. Creating a manual Invoice on a given customer, ALL pending invoice items will be pulled in. I might reach out to Stripe to give them feedback on your use case.

Comment: @duck, thanks for the heads up. That's a shame.

Comment: As of 10/13/21 this still isn't possible.  Spoke with Stripe support today to confirm - generating an invoice will pull in all pending invoice items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking, I am using Stripe's API to delete all pending invoice items from the customer before creating the new invoice items and creating the invoice. Best solution I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure when it was added, but Invoices now can set the [`pending_invoice_items_behavior`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-pending_invoice_items_behavior) to define the behavior.

> How to handle pending invoice items on invoice creation. One of
> include, exclude, or include_and_require. include will include any
> pending invoice items, and will create an empty draft invoice if no
> pending invoice items exist. include_and_require will include any
> pending invoice items, if no pending invoice items exist then the
> request will fail. exclude will always create an empty invoice draft
> regardless if there are pending invoice items or not. Defaults to
> include_and_require if the parameter is omitted.